# how to transfer file to Windows 10 PC using SFTP command?

Tags: ssh, windows, data-transfer, file-sharing, scp

I'm trying the following command from the Pi to the PC (169.254.112.124):

```
sftp pi@169.254.112.124:/C:/Users/Desktop/testtest.xml
```

But I get this error:

> ssh: connect to host 169.254.112.124 port 22: Connection refused
>   Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

I've enabled the 22 port in the server (a Windows 10 PC) by allowing inbound and outbound connections through that port. Also, the firewall is off.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Where in the manual did you find that command? Anyhow the question is not Pi specific.

Comment: what happens if you simply sftp pi@169.254.112.124 without the rest?

Comment: @papatrexas II followed this tutorial https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse and I can get in, but it asks me a password and I don't know which one it is. Any idea? THANK YOU!

Comment: This is not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi. I don't believe that you will find much support here to configure a MS Windows PC. You should better ask at MS Windows forum.

Comment: "but it asks me a password and I don't know which one it is" - what are the choices? My guess is, you'll want the windows 10 users password - do you have a user named `pi` on windows 10, because that's the user you are trying to authenticate with

Comment: Who knows what Windows will do with a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)

Comment: @itd you will need to add an account in your windows pc, an account your raspberry will use to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) in order to configure SSH in the Windows PC where the files are and then, in the Pi I did:

```
sftp user@169.254.112.124:/C:/Users/Desktop/testtest.xml
```

The user is the Windows user for login and the IP is the Windows IP too. Then, it asks me for a password and it's the login password to my Windows PC.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.